# Confusing sentence on Instagram app submission page

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm working on an Instagram app that fetches media based on a tag, ideal for events such as weddings and parties.

Instagram has very strict rules on what kind of third party apps are allowed, the app must fall in one of their three use cases.

To make a long story short, my app was declined because it wasn't a valid use case.

My app used this use case:

> To help broadcasters and publishers discover content, get digital
>   rights to media, and share media with proper attribution

I found more detailed description on this use case, but it doesn't really help.

> This use case is meant for products that don't have a public facing
>   login integration, but are gated to broadcasters and publishers. The
>   product must support either multiple broadcasters and publishers, or
>   multiple users within a single broadcasters or publisher organization.

Is it just me, or is this sentence really confusing? Could someone explain what they mean by broadcasters and publishers in context with Instagram? And what `proper attribution` means?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I think this question could have a high probability of being answered in http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the internet, broadcasters and publishers may be the same people and the term is perhaps used collectively here.

In terms of process, authors create the work, publishers issue it, and broadcasters make it available. Proper attribution means that the source is noted in a suitable format.

Here are the dictionary definitions:

> **Publisher** *noun*
> 1 A company or person that prepares and issues books, journals, or music for sale
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/publisher)
>
> **Broadcaster** *noun*
> 1 An organization that transmits a programme or information by radio or television
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/broadcaster)
>
> **Attribution** *noun*
> 1.1 The action of ascribing a work or remark to a particular author, artist, or person
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/attribution)